# Sort and Filter supported list in sync with EF entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I need to write a wrapper that would allow me to sort and filter a QueryObject without loosing the sync capabilities of the object (it's for DataGridView data binding).

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575%28VS.103%29.aspx) seems like what I need, but it's in the upcomming (beta I think?) EF 5, while I'm still only on EF 3.5. I need to mimic that feature in a older version.

I found a [wrapper](http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/) that enabled me to sort, but not filter and I fail to figure out which path to take to add Filter support in this wrapper. This wrapper also looses the sync with the QueryObject, but I don't think that would be hard to fix.

Comment: If you're using .NET 3.5, you're using EF 3.5, EF1 shipped with .NET 2.0.

Comment: So when you say "allow me to sort and filter" are you talking about server side sorting and filtering (ie. sends the appropriate `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses to the SQL server)?

Comment: Not even, just client side. Basically, I want to be able to use the native BindingSource filter and sorting features with EF 3.5 (Filter will be used programatically and Sort will be used by the DataGridView controls) The goal is to avoid changing the datasource every time.

Comment: Why can't you just new up a `BindingList<T>` then?  `BindingList<MyEntity> bindingList = new BindingList<MyEntity>(MyContext.MyEntities);`

Comment: I would loose the sync with EF (so I would need to at least wrap BindingList) and it doesn't support Filtering anyway.

Comment: By sync you mean you want to make updates to the objects in the binding list and then save them back to the context?

Comment: Im writing a implementation of IBindingListView that would keep an instance of ObjectQuery<T> at the moment. It's the only way I found so far... but it feels like so much work for such a simple task.

Comment: Yes. And I want the DataGridView to be able to do it on his own (up to the Context) so that a DataGridView RowValidated event can simply call SaveChanges().

Comment: I think for Winforms (I'm assuming you're using Winforms here) and .NET/EF 3.5 you're limited to implementing that yourself.

Comment: That's what I think too, unfortunatly. I wish they added that feature from EF a lot sooner :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend BindingSource to create a seperation from the displayed data and the actual data. After that, using Dynamic LINQ, it is possible to write filter methods that will work with any type of data.

```
if (f.Value.type == AdvFilterTypes.Contains)
    tmpList = tmpList.AsQueryable().Where(f.Value.property + ".Contains(\"" + f.Value.condition.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\")");
else
    tmpList = tmpList.AsQueryable().Where(f.Value.property + " " + f.Value.typeSymbole + " " + f.Value.condition);
```